# Polling a subprocess using pid

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I have a django project in which allows a user to start multiple subprocesses at a time. The processes may take some time and thus the user can continue working with other aspects of the app. AT any instance the user can view all the running processes and poll any one of them to check if its over. For this I need to poll the process using its pid. Popen.poll() expects a subprocess.Peopen object while all I have is the pid of that object. How can I get the desired result?

in models.py:

```
class Runningprocess(models.Model):
    #some other fields
    p_id=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.field1
```

In views.py:

```
def run_process():
    ....
    p= subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell =True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    new_p=Runningprocess()  
    new_p.p_id=p.pid
    ....
    new_p.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')   

def check(request,pid):
    #here i want to be able to poll the subprocess using the p_id e.g something like:
     checkp = pid.poll() #this statement is wrong
     if checkp is None:
           do something
     else:
           do something else
```

I just need a valid statement instead of 'checkp = pid.poll()'

Comment: Can you show a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: See the edited question

Comment: Not suggesting this is a good idea in your particular case, but to check if a process with a specific PID is running, you can use `os.kill(pid, 0)` which raises `OSError` if no process with that PID is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't poll with PID**

PID is a temporary ID assigned to a process. It stays with a process as long as process is running. When a process either terminates or get killed, its PID may(or may not immediately) get assigned to some other process. So, a PID of a process, which is valid now, may not remain valid after sometime.

Now, how to poll for a process?

This is what I did in one of my project:

```
psub = subprocess.Popen(something)
# polling

while psub.poll() is None:
    pass
```

but beware, the above code might result into a deadlock. To avoid deadlock you can use two approaches:

1. Use counter. When counter value become greater than some fixed value - kill the process.

2.Use timeout. Get the start time when process started and when process takes longer than a fixed time - kill.

```
start_time = time.time()
timeout = 60 # 60 seconds
while psub.poll() is None:
    if time.time() - start_tym >= int(timeout):
        psub.kill()
```

Comment: The problem is that the user can access the view 'run_process()' multiple times from different locations on the webapp and accordingly different processes are started. At a particular url I list all the processes that are currently saved in Runningprocesses model and clicking on any of them redirects the user to 'check' where I need to check whether that particular process is still under process or not. If it is done I want certain things to happen along with it getting deleted from that model.

Comment: @Code_aholic AFAIK, PID is not reliable. What you can do for your case is. Keep running controller of `run_process()` in an asynchronous Popen() process. Store the process PID in DB now let the started process write to DB for each stage like 'init', 'killed', 'complete'. Whenever the webapp user clicks the PID show data from DB.

Comment: Oh well, I think its worth giving a shot. I should have thought of it that ways! Thanks :). Although I have one concern, the process may take upto few hours as well so would this method work fine in that case?

Comment: If it was helpful, you can close the question by accepting the answer.

Comment: The process may take upto few hours as well so would this method work fine in that case?

Comment: It will work for as long as your program runs.